# grub rescue prompt after boot-repair

Tags: linux-mint, grub

I want to run Windows 8 and Linux Mint 15 in dual boot. After installing Mint I could no longer boot Windows 8. After running boot-repair from a USB device I can't boot either of them anymore. I just get a grub rescue prompt preceded by

```
error: no such device: 44d9d480-e343-437e-9384-03495c5d89de.
```

This is the boot-repair log URL: http://paste2.org/nEhbEbUk

Why am I receiving this error? What can I do to fix it?

*I originally posted this question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307030/grub-rescue-prompt-after-boot-repair but was advised to ask it here*

Comment: I am not sure whether I can answer my own question, but it is working now!
I changed my BIOS settings as follows:
- set 'Launch CMS' to 'auto'
- set 'OS Type' to 'Windows 8 UEFI'
- set 'Secure Boot Mode' to 'Standard'
Make sure to boot from the strick in UEFI mode!

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your BIOS to boot from sdb as boot-repair suggested at the very end?

Many BIOSes have a feature that allows you to choose a boot device by pressing a key (perhaps F12) during the Power On Self Test (POST). From there, try picking your second hard drive.

If that works, you can go into your BIOS configuration and make that change permanent.

If not, you might explore this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155239